# Can't install both Xubuntu and Lubuntu using Wubi

Tags: wubi

I am attempting to install Lubuntu using Wubi installer, however I am not succeeding. The installation process on Windows goes fine, then Wubi demands reboot, I do so and choose Lubuntu from the Windows boot menu. Then it loads and at some point, it always fails, reporting an installation error due to issue with media, implying that media is dirty is or damaged. This is happening both with Lubuntu and Xubuntu. Oddly, I was able to install Ubuntu, but this is an old desktop and Ubuntu doesn't run smoothly, so I need to look for the lighter alternatives LXDE and Xfce.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to "Check the Disk for Errors" in Windows? Wubi installs are very susceptible to errors in the Windows NTFS filesystem

Comment: Hum, I will check it now. I am installing the files on D: partition, which only has documents and is mostly free space, so it may have some corruption I haven't noticed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I finally managed to install Lubuntu with Wubi.

The problem was, most likely, related to overheating activity of the CPU, given the facts that the ventilation system of this desktop needs to be improved and the error window was repeatedly reporting file copying errors from the installation media. So the first thing I did today after a night of rest was this installation and it worked because the PC was cold enough to prevent any errors.